# Seeking free tool to create elevation profile for map

Tags: export, software-recommendations, elevation, free-software

It is a plus if it supports a little bit of programming.

I need a more or less free tool to create an elevation profile of the mountain route - I have a start and end city for this route, also maybe I want to add some points in between. I need a height map from the side of the route. I want to add some labels in between, maybe manually. I am a programmer, so potentially I see it a good thing to add some lines of code, as it is possible in this app - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-ElevationProfile.html, https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-elevation-profile/ -, which seems to be near ideal, a little bit too much programming, but 1500€ is too much money for me. Maybe I could do with 20€, but free tools are the closest.

I want to do some manual work, so it would add a lot to export to Illustrator or LibreOffice Draw (I gain from simplicity, and some manual work).

So, Ideally, I do this:

- Choose Create Elevation Profile from somewhere
- Enter two cities
- Get an elevation profile image
- Choose, manually, some points and hightlight them, so that they are easy to see later
- Not importantly, but might have some way to write a few lines of code to do something with chosen points, or label colors etc. I am happy if I have to draw them manually.
- Export the result to Illustrator or free drawing app, or SVG file, and work with this to add some labels, titles, and change colors or other things about my Elevation Profile.

Application to do this should be free or very cheap, prefferably usable for some programming - like ArcGIS, which is quite visual tool, but does not leave programmer to starve - and I prefer visual interface.

If you see a solution to this, which uses a few lines of code to generate something in JavaScript or other programming language, and do the similar operations - draw path, select some points for labels, export to illustrator. Similarly, use a free or cheap product/library for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at QGIS and the "Profile tool" plugin. QGIS has a well documented Python API, so you could customize as you wish.